# Word or expression for a dismissive hand gesture

Tags: expressions

I need a word or expression for a slightly rude and dismissive hand gesture that could accompany an eye roll.

Jake and Tom are art students. Stacy is majoring in accounting.
Jake discusses byzantine art with Tom. They seem absorbed in the conversation, when Stacy intervenes making the remark that byzantine art seems influenced by the Gospels. Jake rolls his eyes and performs a `dismissive hand gesture`.

I think that "wave her away" would fit. Are there better choices?

Comment: No special term, but either _waves it off_ or _waves her off_ would be understood in this context.

Comment: It depends on the specific gesture. Maybe you can find a video that illustrates the one you're talking about?

Comment: I need to specify that I'm not an American, so I don't know the appropriate dismissive body language in US. In my country, you just wave people away with a few flicks of a wrist, the back of the hand being towards the person that gets waved off. This is something that used to happen to me a lot as a kid when barging into grown up conversations.

Comment: @RichardKayser It is rude. I'm not sure if it's not too rude, because Stacy is their equal. The eye roll is already offensive. But art is not Stacy's business, so maybe a different gesture would make her understand she's not competent enough to meaningfully contribute to their discussion.

Comment: @Stockfish I think it would do. Is there a specific gesture for that. I'm from Mordor. Sauron has forsaken us years ago and now we and the orcs are living in a dystopian reality.